# Binding DropDown List with the Data Reader results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable

I want to bind a Html.DropDown list with the values that I have in a data reader.

Following few examples I converted my DataReader into an Enumerator through `GetEnumerator` 
Method and than in Controller trying to cast is as a SelectList through `Cast<SelectList>().GetEnumerator()` but here I am getting an error that:

```
'System.Collections.IEnumerator' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Cast<TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has some invalid arguments D:\Dev\MYPROJECT\MYPROJECT\MYPROJECT\Controllers\UserController.cs
```

Can anyone help me find out how can I bind my Drop own list with the results from the database.

`In Model:`

```
var prsnsInfo = new string[3];
IEnumerator Iprsns = null;

try
{
if (prsns != null || prsns.HasRows)
    Iprsns = prsns.GetEnumerator();
}

catch (Exception ex) { }
return Iprsns;
```

`in Controller:`

```
var prsns = ModelObj.GetPersons(1);
ViewBag.prsns = prsns.Cast<SelectList>().GetEnumerator();
```

`in View:`

```
@Html.DropDownList("person",(IEnumerable<SelectList>)ViewBag.prsns)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using .Select

ViewBag.prsns = prsns.Select(x => new SelectListItem {Text = x.ID, Value = x.Name}).ToList()

(ID and Name are assumed fields, replace them withe the fields that correspond to your needs)

Comment: With this It is giving this error: `'System.Collections.IEnumerator' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`